# Ruby on Railsをターミナルで環境設定する際のエラー(Warning:)について教えて下さい。

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails, macos

ターミナルを初めて使ってruby on railsの環境を設定しています。ruby/rails/gemというもののアップデートを行っております。Mac OS X 10.9.5です。
それぞれのバージョンは

ruby 2.0.0p481 (2014-05-08 revision 45883) [universal.x86_64-darwin13]
Rails 4.2.1
gem 2.4.6
です。
そこで確か cd my_app(my_appというディレクトリを動画を見ながらターミナルで
作ってあります。)というコマンドを実行したところ
かなりの頻度で以下のエラーが出てきます。

Warning: Running `gem pristine --all` to regenerate your installed gemspecs (and deleting then reinstalling your bundle if you use bundle --path) will improve the startup performance of Spring.

これが何を示すのか調べたのですがさっぱり検討がつきません。初歩的な質問かもしれませんが
ぜひお知恵をおかりしたくよろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

＞cd my_app というコマンドを実行したところ

cdというコマンドで表示されたというのは、何かの間違いだと思います。
その警告は、railsをspring経由で実行しようとすると表示されるもので。
cd(change directory)で表示されるものではありません。
実際に警告を発しているコードは、以下をご確認ください。
( 参照: https://github.com/rails/spring/blob/master/bin/spring#L39-L41 )

Gem::Specification(Gemのメタデータ)から情報を絞り込んでいって、
最終的にunstubbed配列に、何かしらデータが含まれていると警告を発するようです。
その絞り込み方は、specifications/defaultディレクトリを見ていたり。stubbed?メソッドの真偽値を利用していて、少々複雑なのですが気になるのであれば先に示したコードの部分を、script runner等で実行して値を確認してみると良いでしょう。(それでどのgemが問題になっているのかも分かるはずです)

確保済のメタデータに、何かしらの差異が生じてしまっていると考えられますので
素直に`gem pristine --all`して、警告を解決されて良いと思います。

Comment: 初めて利用させていただいたので**Stackoverflow**をうまく使えているか不安だったのですがご回答お寄せいただき御礼申し上げます。大変助かっています。教えて頂いておりますgem pristine --allをターミナルで実行してみたのですが、 `ERROR: While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError) You don't have write permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0 directory.` と返されてしまいGoogleでも調べてみたのですがなかなかうまい解決方法が見つからず困っています。(約17826日間Webをがんばる日記 [goo.gl/OoIJgN] 他参照はしてみたのですが解決に導けず) またご教示頂いた_script runner_については_script runner_関連の記事を調べてはいるのですがどのように使うか（ブログなどについては関連してそうなコマンドらしきものが記載されているのですがこれで正しいのかどうかもわからず）困惑しております。お手数をお掛けしますがよろしければ更にお知恵をお借りさせていただければ幸いです。よろしくお願いします。

Comment: @mimi-karaage /Library/Rubyを参照しているということは、その環境がシステム共有(root権限)で構築されているようですね。 sudo されても良いのですがhttp://changesworlds.com/2014/07/install-without-adm-on-the-rubygems/ こちらなどを参照しつつ。rbenvで環境構築したほうが切替等が容易ですのでやってみてください。

Comment: @MimiKaraage ご自身で参照された [105日目-Railsのインストール手順 - 約17826日間Webをがんばる日記](http://ruby-sato.hatenablog.com/entry/2014/03/18/032131) に記載の通りrbenvインストール作業そしてRubyとRailsのインストール作業を行ってみてはいかがでしょうか。Rubyのバージョンは2.2.1か2.1.5にしましょう。「7.MySQL」は飛ばしても良いでしょう。

Comment: @NorikazIshii ご回答お寄せいただきありがとうございます。おっしゃっていただいたようにsudoで実行してみたのですが、やはりエラーが出てしまっていたので困っていました。回答ありがとうございます。rbenvで環境構築出来たのではないかと思います。

Comment: @riocampos 
以前参考にしたとお知らせしたサイトに加えて具体的にどのようにインストールするのかご教示いただきありがとうございます。
バージョンについてはおっしゃっていただいたように2.2.1でインストールをしました
(7.MySQLについてはお伝えいただいた通りインストールを飛ばしてみました･･･もしかしたら今後必要になるのかもしれないのですが今の私のレベルと勘案してやめておこうと思いました。)詳細にご教示いただきありがとうございました。